# Does a Derived Class allocate memory for the inherited variable, or it just gets access to it?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, memory, allocation

```
// c++ class inheritance
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int x;
};

class B: public A
{
};
int main()
{
    B b;
    b.x=5;
    cout<<b.x<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Does a Derived Class allocate memory for the inherited variable, or it just gets access to it from the Base Class??

Answer (score 1):

The base class, effectively, becomes a field inside the derived class. Almost as if you did:

```
struct A {
  int i;
};

struct B {
  A __base_a;
};
```

So, when you do `b.x` it is almost as if you did `b.__base_a.x`.

This is not exactly what happens, but it's a good conceptual model.

Answer (score 0):

The memory for the variable is only allocated once. The derived class merely gets access to it and extends the base class by possibly members of its own. The derived class IS A base class, plus its own variables.